Pylance error: Unpacking TypedDict into Flask-SQLAlchemy table
Why does pylance complain about "Unable to match unpacked TypedDict argument to parameters" for this code?
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from typing import TypedDict

db2 = SQLAlchemy()

class MyTable(db2.Model):
    var1 = db2.Column(db2.Integer)
    var2 = db2.Column(db2.String)

class MyDict(TypedDict):
    var1: int
    var2: str

def myfun(mydict: MyDict):
    myrow = MyTable(**mydict)

Pylance error:
Unable to match unpacked TypedDict argument to parameters
  No parameter named "var1"
  No parameter named "var2"PylancereportCallIssue
(parameter) mydict: MyDict


Looks like you can't make flask_sqlalchemy play well with static typing. https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/4646 - db2.Model (a property of a variable) is a very big red flag, mypy will fail right there (Name "db2.Model" is not defined  [name-defined]) and pyright apparently tries its best but still can't handle that, defaulting to no-arg __init__ (try reveal_type(MyTable.__init__))
